# Reliable QWidget to QImage coordinate transformation?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4, pyside

Mouse click events include click coordinates that are relative to the `QWidget` window in which the click occurred.

Assuming that the widget is displaying an image (*i.e.* the `QWidget` contains a `QLabel` whose `QPixmap` was built from a `QImage`), how can the mouse click position be converted into the `QImage` coordinates?

Comment: The simplest solution is to create a custom widget that displays the image and indicates the clicks via a signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the most convenient solution is to process mouse clicks at the `QLabel` level instead of the `QWidget` in which it is included. In this case no conversion is needed.